# Test performance in Openshift and prevent get banned IP

Tags: openshift, newrelic, openshift-cartridge, datadog

I have an application hosted in openshift. Now I want figure out how many request can handle in order to check the speed and availability.

So my first attempt will be generate a multiple HTTP GET requests to my Rest Service(made in python and hosted in openshift).

My fear is can get my IP workplace banned regarding this looks like an attack.

In the other hand I see there are tools like [New Relic](https://hub.openshift.com/addons/15-newrelic) or [DataDog](https://hub.openshift.com/addons/31-datadog) to check metrics, but I don't know if I can simulate http requests and then check the response times.

## **Openshift Response**

***I finally wrote to Openshift support and they told me I can simulate http requests without worries.***

Comment: Any advice? or any other aproach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall the default behavior being that each gear can handle 16 concurrent connections, then auto-scaling would kick in and you would get a new gear. Therefore I would think it makes sense to start by testing that a gear works well with 16 users at once. If not, then you can [change the scaling policy](https://blog.openshift.com/customizing-autoscale-functionality-in-openshift/) to what works best for you application.

[BlazeMeter](https://marketplace.openshift.com/apps/5189#!overview) is a tool that could probably help with creating the connections. They mention 100,000 concurrent users on that main page so I don't think you have to worry about getting banned for this sort of test.

Comment: Thanks for replay :), I forgot about 16 concurrent connections limit. Anyway I like to know If I can do it by myself, I mean, create a simple java(or any other language) program to generate many of HTTP GET requests.

Comment: It would be difficult to create a very large number of concurrent requests from a single machine, but to get started and test the app scaled across a few gears I think it is reasonable to do yourself.

Comment: I pretend use threads to simulate concurrent connections. How many? I think only depends of the bandwith of my workplace, right?